# Two Ajax requests depending on the response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two ajax requests however I just want to execute the other Ajax depending on the response of the first Ajax Request, however I am not getting a response in the second ajax call. What do you think is the problem? Thank you in advance.

This is the sample code

```
// first ajax call
$.ajax({ 
  dataType: "json",
  url: "index.json",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    sn: $(this).attr("data-sn")
  }),
  success: function(data) {
   if (JSON.stringify(data) !== "{}") {
     // second ajax call
     $.ajax({ 
       dataType: "json",
       url: "index2.json",
       data: JSON.stringify({
         sn: $(this).attr("data-sn")
       }),
       success: function(data) {
         console.log("Test");
       }
     });   
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Does second call fails? Check console network tab.

Comment: Is your second ajax call hitting index2.json file?

Comment: I am successfully calling the console.log(''Test"), however my response returns an empty object

Comment: Did you check that your second ajax request working after success of first?

Comment: Did you check data in console.log(data)

Comment: So issue comes from server side `index2.json` which is empty obviously

Comment: I'm assuming that the missing `}` was just from copying into the question (fixed in edit)

Comment: In case of missing }, how ajax call made? This will generate error.